# What managers write while their team is playing

Tags: football, coaching

I always wonder what football (club) managers write on their notepad while their team is playing.

In today's games we are presented with all sorts of statistics of both individual and team performances, so what kind of information they keep on scribbling and how does that help them?

Comment: Just some guessing, but statistics do not show when a certain situation went wrong and what went wrong. They might write down the minute of the game it happened, for when he reviews the game afterward. What happened, with who it happened if he wants to point something out at halftime for example. And maybe his idea for a solution if applicable. Basically it's just to make sure to not forget something.

Comment: Ya Right, and we know the importance of manager's half time talk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Don_Biglia mentioned, there's no way of knowing what a manager writes on his notepad. But some intelligent guesswork would suggest he/she is keeping a note of certain points about the game. It could be anything from a list of things to say at half time to individual advice to be given to certain players. Of course for all we know he/she could just be doodling as well, probably a technique to keep oneself calm. Many managers do not write anything, leaving that job to one of his/her assistants. Basically, it's up to the individual manager to do what he/she wants during a match, as long as he/she stays within the technical area and does not engage in any unsportsmanlike behaviour.

Comment: red_devil226, I wish somebody peek into Louis Van Gal's notepad ;)

Comment: Oh we know what's on LVG's notepad. Possession possession possession (and hopefully there's a chance to score a goal). :P